# (Error) django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table "" with primary key "' has an invalid foreign key

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get the primary key of my User model (which is not the default pk) by using a ForeignKey and then, with a property, get the "usertag" of the User model, but when I try migrating my changes I get the following error:

***django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'user_friend' with primary key 'LOL' has an invalid foreign key: user_friend.fk_id contains a value 'fk_id' that does not have a corresponding value in user_user.id.***

My models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    f_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    l_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    usertag = models.CharField(max_length=7, default="aabb11")
    level = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    profile_pic = models.URLField(max_length=10000)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=25)


class invites(models.Model):
    invite_id = models.CharField(max_length=8, primary_key=True)
    choices = [("P", "PENDING"), ("A", "ACCEPTED"), ("D", "DECLINED")]
    sent_to = models.CharField(max_length=7) 
    from_user = models.CharField(max_length=7) 
    invite_status = models.CharField(choices=choices, default=choices[0], max_length=9)


# USE Foreign KEYS
class friend(models.Model):
    fk = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_constraint=False)
    friend_tag = models.CharField(max_length=7, primary_key=True)

    @property
    def my_tag(self):
        return self.fk.usertag
```

Comment: fk = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_constraint=False, null=True, blank=True) or if you dont want to give that property then delete database using command python manage.py flush and then migrate